# How to handle HTTP Response 500 error code through Ajax ".fail()" trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I was running some jQuery code when suddenly I saw through Firebug Console that when I force a 500 error, the code inside .fail() method, is not being fired:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "someAction.do",
   data: "param1=param&param2=param",
   dataType: "xml"
}).done(function(xml){ 
   //some stuff with my data 
}).fail(function(xml){
   //some other different stuff with my data that is not being fired

});
```

In the other hand, in a Java Action, I set the HttpResponse Status to "500" when an error occurs, for example, POSTING an invalid field trough the Ajax call, like searching in a database for an email that is not present, and then show the error trough ajax:

`<xml version=bla,bla...>
    <item>
      <name>message</name>
      <value>Invalid input data</value>
    </item>
   </xml>`.

Any ideas why? I just want to use the new methods **fail()** and **done()**. **I know I could do this using the statusCode handler**.

But I allways like to follow new trends if I could. At least I would like to try that.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does `error` piece set `header` response code to `500` ? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? How do I set the status? I code response.setHeader("Status", "500"); and then response.setStatus(500); because I do not know which one es better. I am a front-end, Java superjunior. Thanks

Comment: See http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/servlets/http_status_code.shtml

Comment: Thank you for that, but I am doing exactly what is said there.

Comment: If possible , try adding `textStatus` to `done` and `fail` handlers , and `console.log(textStatus)` to handler body , post return value of `textStatus` ?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach , substitute direct call to `.done()` or `.fail()` by filtering responses through `.always()` initially , then calling `.done()` or `.fail()` through filtering deferred ; maintaining ability to process actual net errors with same `fail()` callback

```
// simulate server-side responses 
var error = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" 
            + "<item>" 
            + "<name>message</name>" 
            + "<value>Invalid input data</value>" 
            + "</item>";

var success = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" 
            + "<item>" 
            + "<name>message</name>" 
            + "<value>Success</value>" + "</item>";
// params
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend : function(jqxhr, settings) {
        var d = decodeURIComponent(settings.data)
                    .match(/data=+.*/)[0]
                    .split(/=|&/);
        var params = {};
        params[d[0]] = {};
        params[d[0]][d[1]] = d[2];
        params[d[0]][d[3]] = d[4];
        jqxhr.data = params;
    }
});

var request = function (url, _xmlResponse, data1, data2) {
    var _response = new $.Deferred(),
        _request = $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                // responses
                xml: _xmlResponse,
                // params
                data: "param1="+ data1 +"&param2="+ data2
            },
            dataType: "xml"
        });
    // check `responseText` for "Invalid" , 
    // check `textStatus` for actual net error , "error"
    _request.always(function (xml, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        console.log(xml, textStatus, jqxhr, "check");
        // simulate server-side processing, cont. 
        // if both object passed to server , 
        // `param1` and `param2` _do not_ have property 
        // with value of at `params` ,  `""` empty string - generic "error" ,
        // _and_  returned `responseText` contain "Invalid" ,
        // _or_ `textStatus` : `error` , `reject` `dfd` , call `.fail()`
        // else `resolve `dfd` , call `.done()`

        // check params
        var test = [xml["data"] || jqxhr["data"]].every(function(v, k) {
          return !(v.data["param1"] !== "" && v.data["param2"] !== "" )
        }) ; 
        // check `xml` responseText for node for "Invalid" text ,
        // generate `.fail()`
        var check = $(xml.children)
        .find("value").is(":contains(Invalid)");
        return check && test || textStatus === "error"
               // call `.fail()`
               ? _response.reject([xml, textStatus, jqxhr]) 
               // call `.done()`
               : _response.resolve([xml, textStatus, jqxhr])
    });

    return _response
    .done(function (xml) {
        // do `done()` stuff
        console.log(xml[0], xml[1], xml[2]);
        var msg = $(xml[0].children).find("value").html();
        $("#success")
        .html(msg + ", " 
                  + xml[2].data.data.param1 
                  + xml[2].data.data.param2
             );
        return this.promise()
    })
    .fail(function (xml) {
        // do `.fail()` stuff
        console.log(xml[0], xml[1], xml[2], "fail");
        var msg = $(xml[0].children).find("value").html() 
                  || xml[1] + ", " + xml[2];
        $("#error")
        .html(msg);
        return this.promise()
    });
};
```

Could then call `request()` , without `_xmlResponse` param , which should handle both generated `.fail()` (if `responseText` contains "Invalid") and  net error `.fail()` calls (e.g., `statusCode` `500`; `textStatus` `error`) , and `.done()` calls .

```
request("someAction.do", "param1_param", "param2_param");
```

Optionally, chain returned `promise` from `request` at `.always()` , as `data` array containing `request` return values ; after being processed at `.done()` or `fail()`

```
request("someAction.do", "param1_param", "param2_param")
.always(function(data) {
  // do `.done()` , `.fail()` stuff ,
  // `data, textStatus, jqxhr`
  console.log(data[0], data[1], data[2])
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/ek15krb5/

Answer (score 0):

I think that depends on the parameter  "xml", if:
1. xml is a real xml object ,it'll trigger 'done';
2. xml is not a xml object ,it'll trigger 'fail'

Even if you return a 500 error code ,it is still a valid xml object, So it'll trigger "done"